# Detecting when NSTextField becomes active

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nstextfield

To be specific I would like to receive notifications when an `NSTextField` gets focus, or when the user clicks on it and is about to start editing.

I've tried the `textDidBeginEditing:` method but this is only fired when the user actually starts to type and I need it when the text field becomes the first responder.

I've tried overriding `-(BOOL)becomeFirstResponder` but that's only called when the text field ***first*** becomes the first responder and not any time after that.

I've tried registering for `NSControlDidBeginEditing` notifications but never got any.

Is this possible?

Comment: In my test app `becomeFirstResponder` is called every time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Implement the window's delegate method [`windowWillReturnFieldEditor:toObject:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSWindowDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSWindowDelegate/windowWillReturnFieldEditor:toObject:). This tells you that the field editor is switching to a different object. Look to see if this object is the text field.

Alternatively, subclass NSWindow and override [`makeFirstResponder:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindow_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSWindow/makeFirstResponder:). Call `super`, look to see what responder is becoming first responder and whether the call to `super` returned YES, and return the result of the call to `super`.

Comment: The first option doesn't really work as you get inundated with calls to the delegate method that don't always tie in with when it becomes first responder. The second option is the money maker. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Just to be clear `@matt`'s answer put me on the right path; I thought I just ought to clarify exactly how you can do this.

> Aim

So I wanted to have an `NSTextField` subclass that would know when it became active (i.e. first responder), and then notify it's delegate.

> Problem

It turns out the under the hood of OS X text editing is a messy world and you can't really rely on `NSTextField` to do it all. Basically when an object that is involved in text editing becomes the first responder, something (the window, the system, the `NSApplication`) gives it an `_NSKeyboardClipView` (I think it's called that...) as a subview. In turn the `_NSKeyboardClipView` has an `NSTextView` as a subview, ***and it's the `NSTextView` that becomes the first responder***.

> Solution

• Subclass (or extend) NSWindow and override the `makeFirstResponder:` method.

• Fire a notification using `NSNotificationCenter` who's object is the responder object that is passed to the `makeFirstResponder:` method.

• Catch the notification in your `NSTextField` subclass.

• Here's the horrible bit: you need to check that the `notification.object` is, a) a subclass of `NSView` and, b) the `notification.object.superview.superview  == self` (you will have to cast to `NSView` here because the object will be of type `id`). e.g:

```
- (void)didBecomeFirstResponder:(NSNotification *)note
{
    if ([note.object isKindOfClass:[NSView class]] && [[(NSView *)note.object superview] superview] == self) {
        // You just became the first responder
    }
}
```

It's horrible and tacky/hacky but it does work.

Comment: In my test app `makeFirstResponder` is also called with the textfield. The test in `didBecomeFirstResponder` is simply `note.object = self`.

Comment: @Willeke yes it does call it but only the first time.

Comment: Weird, like `becomeFirstResponder`, `makeFirstResponder` is called every time.

Comment: Very belated followup: tested this on Big Sur beta 2: `becomeFirstResponder` is called each time the text field gets focus. It then resigns `firstResponder` to the field editor. Also, `textDidEndEditing` is called every time the field loses focus, even when no text has been entered. This might be easier and less fragile than spelunking the view hierarchy when the field editor gets focus